# Angular JS single controller multiple views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

Is it a good practice to have one controller, but two different html file templates that shows same data but in different format.

Basically I need slightly different template to present the view on a modal dialog and different template to show when it is called on a web page.  Any suggestions, advice is appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

It is totally fine to share one controller between multiple views. In fact this in one of the strengths of decoupling the javascript from the view like Angular code helps you do. 
Different views can share the same logic but still render different markup.